# Redireccionar a página Symfony con redirecToRoute() más parámetro

Tags: php, symfony3

Buenas,

Intento realizar una redirección una vez terminado el envío  del formulario, pero me salta un error todo el tiempo. Lo he intentado realizar de diversas formas, pero no encuentro la solución. Viendo la documentación, incluso haciendo lo mismo que allí se indica, no hay forma de hacer la redirección.

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::renderBlock() must be an instance
>   of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, instance of
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse given

```
public function indexAction(Request $request) {
            $sendOk = NULL;
            if($request->get('ok') != NULL){
                $sendOk = $request->get('ok');
            }

        if($sendOk != NULL){
            return $this->render('FrontendBundle:Contact:contact.html.twig', array(
                        'form' => $this->generateFormAction($request),
                        'ok' => $sendOk
                            )
            );
        }else{
            return $this->render('FrontendBundle:Contact:contact.html.twig', array(
                        'form' => $this->generateFormAction($request)
                            )
            );
        }
    }

    public function generateFormAction(Request $request) {

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
                ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
                    'label_attr' => array('class' => 'control-label'),
                    'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'form.contact.placeholder.name', 'class' => 'form-control'),
                    'constraints' => array(
                        new NotBlank(array("message" => "Por favor, indique un nombre")),),
                    'label' => 'form.contact.name',
                ))
                ->add('surname', TextType::class, array(
                    'label_attr' => array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label'),
                    'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'form.contact.placeholder.surname', 'class' => 'form-control'),
                    'constraints' => array(
                        new NotBlank(array("message" => "Por favor, indique sus apellidos")),),
                    'label' => 'form.contact.surname',
                ))
                ->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
                    'label_attr' => array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label'),
                    'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'form.contact.placeholder.email', 'class' => 'form-control'),
                    'constraints' => array(
                        new NotBlank(array("message" => "Por favor, indique un email válido")),
                        new Email(array("message" => "Su email no parece ser válido")),),
                    'label' => 'form.contact.email',
                ))
                ->add('phone', NumberType::class, array(
                    'required' => false,
                    'label_attr' => array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label'),
                    'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'form.contact.placeholder.phone', 'class' => 'form-control', 'novalidate' => 'novalidate'),
                    'label' => 'form.contact.phone',
                ))
                ->add('message', TextareaType::class, array(
                    'label_attr' => array('class' => 'control-label'),
                    'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'form.contact.placeholder.message', 'class' => 'textarea form-control'),
                    'constraints' => array(
                        new NotBlank(array("message" => "Por favor, escriba su mensaje")),),
                    'label' => 'form.contact.message',
                ))
                ->add('send', SubmitType::class, array(
                    'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-default', 'onclick' => 'openPopup()'),
                    'label' => 'form.contact.send'))
                ->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            $response = $this->sendMailAction($data);
            return $this->redirectToRoute('f_contact', array('ok' => $response));
        }

        return $form->createView();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fíjate que aquí:

```
'form' => $this->generateFormAction($request),
```

Estás asignando en todos los casos el valor devuelto por `generateFormAction`. Posiblemente en la plantilla estás pasando el valor form a una función de formularios, pero la función `generateFormAction` también devuelve una instancia de `RedirectResponse`, que obviamente no es compatible con lo que la plantilla espera.

Te propongo que en lugar de comprobar si el formulario es correcto en `generateFormAction` lo hagas en la propia `indexAction`

```
<?php 

    public function indexAction(Request $request) {
        $sendOk = NULL;
        if($request->get('ok') != NULL){
            $sendOk = $request->get('ok');
        }

        $form = $this->generateFormAction($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            $response = $this->sendMailAction($data);
            return $this->redirectToRoute('f_contact', array('ok' => $response));
        }

        if($sendOk != NULL){
            return $this->render('FrontendBundle:Contact:contact.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form,
                'ok' => $sendOk
                )
            );
        }else{
            return $this->render('FrontendBundle:Contact:contact.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form
                )
            );
        }
    }

    public function generateFormAction(Request $request) {

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('name', TextType::class, array(
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'control-label'),
            'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'form.contact.placeholder.name', 'class' => 'form-control'),
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotBlank(array("message" => "Por favor, indique un nombre")),),
            'label' => 'form.contact.name',
            ))
        ->add('surname', TextType::class, array(
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label'),
            'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'form.contact.placeholder.surname', 'class' => 'form-control'),
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotBlank(array("message" => "Por favor, indique sus apellidos")),),
            'label' => 'form.contact.surname',
            ))
        ->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label'),
            'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'form.contact.placeholder.email', 'class' => 'form-control'),
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotBlank(array("message" => "Por favor, indique un email válido")),
                new Email(array("message" => "Su email no parece ser válido")),),
            'label' => 'form.contact.email',
            ))
        ->add('phone', NumberType::class, array(
            'required' => false,
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label'),
            'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'form.contact.placeholder.phone', 'class' => 'form-control', 'novalidate' => 'novalidate'),
            'label' => 'form.contact.phone',
            ))
        ->add('message', TextareaType::class, array(
            'label_attr' => array('class' => 'control-label'),
            'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'form.contact.placeholder.message', 'class' => 'textarea form-control'),
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotBlank(array("message" => "Por favor, escriba su mensaje")),),
            'label' => 'form.contact.message',
            ))
        ->add('send', SubmitType::class, array(
            'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-default', 'onclick' => 'openPopup()'),
            'label' => 'form.contact.send'))
        ->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);       

        return $form->createView();
    }
```

Te recomiendo también, que la construcción de los formularios las hagas en clases individuales, esto tiene dos grandes ventajas: la primera es que independizas la lógica del formulario de la del controlador, y por otro lado, el formulario se convierte en una clase reusable en cualquier otro punto de tu código. Tienes más información [aquí](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes).

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Me ha sido de gran ayuda. Únicamente comentarte un error en lo que me has indicado. Conforme me lo has pasado el isSubmitted y isValid no funcionaba, para ello he realizado el $form->createView() cuando se envía el parámetro form al Template y no en la funciona generateFormAction. Tomaré en cuenta las otras directrices que me comentas para futuros formularios. Quitando de eso me has sido de gran ayuda! Todo funciona a la perfección!

Comment: Disculpa, lo he hecho un poco con prisa... Pero la intención era orientarte hacia la "forma correcta".